# Removing levels of indexing in R

Tags: r, list

I've got a bunch of results that a stored as a list of a list of double vectors (a list of different parameters tried from a for loop using the optim function) so when I type list the elements are displayed like:

```
[[1]]
        r         k     sigma 
 96.66667 328.66667 396.33333 
.
.
.
.

[[291]]
    r     k sigma 
 97.0 329.8 397.7 
.
.
.
etc
```

I want to be able to access the minimum and maximum values for the named values "r" "k" and "sigma." 
But R I can't access them using the $ sign, or using quotation marks as R is taking each name as unique within the list within the lsit, I've tried using unlist but that turned the data into a 1000 long vector, and I've tried cbind but neither worked.

I would greatly appreciate any help anyone could offer!

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to rewrite your loop over `optim` so that the `r` values get appended to `yourlist[[1]]$r` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If every element of the list is the same size (vector of length 3) then you can do something like:

```
do.call(rbind, mylist)
```

where `mylist` is your list of output objects.  That will create a matrix (or use `cbind` in place of `rbind`).

Another option to grab just one of the pieces is:

```
sapply( mylist, `[`, "r" )
```

which will grab the "r" element from each vector and simplify that into a single vector if it can.  Replace "r" with the other names to get the other pieces.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to get this into a matrix or dataframe with:

```
mtx <- do.call(rbind, object)
```

You would be able to access indivdual elements by position with:

```
listname[[291]]   # should return 
   r     k sigma 
97.0 329.8 397.7
```